# subprocess.check_output() fails to return command results when pinging ip's

Tags: python, subprocess, ping

I am trying to use subprocess module in python to ping ip addresses. Here is the code.

```py
command = ['ping', '-c', '1', 1.1.1.1]


print((subprocess.check_output(command)).decode("utf-8"))
```

This would return the proper ping result for 1.1.1.1.

```
Ping statistics for 1.1.1.1:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 4ms, Maximum = 4ms, Average = 4ms
```

However, if were to ping an invalid ip, like 0.0.0.0

```py
command = ['ping', '-c', '1', 0.0.0.0]

subprocess.call(command)

print((subprocess.check_output(command)).decode("utf-8"))
```

Then subprocess.call(command) would return

```
Pinging 0.0.0.0 with 32 bytes of data:
PING: transmit failed. General failure. 

Ping statistics for 0.0.0.0:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss)
```

However once the code reaches subprocess.check_output, it will not return anything and all subsequent code following it will not run. How can I have subprocess.check_output() return the full ping statement thrown by subprocess.call()?

Comment: Why are you running the command twice?

Comment: `subprocess.check_output()` raises an exception if the command has a non-zero exit status. And `ping` returns a non-zero status if it can't ping the IP.

Comment: I am making sure that it will run and it does. However it will not output the result.

Comment: It runs, but when the ping fails it returns a non-zero status.

Comment: Why are you passing the IP addresses as (weird) numbers instead of strings? I'd have thought that's a syntax error but not in a place where I can check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.check_output()` raises an exception if the command returns a non-zero exit status, and `ping` does this when it doesn't get a response to the pings.

Instead of using `subprocess.call()` and `subprocess.check_output()`, you should use `subprocess.run()`.

```
command = ['ping', '-c', '1', '1.1.1.1']
print(subprocess.run(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, encoding="utf-8").stdout)
```